# Specified cells with update date of a specific cell

Tags: vba, automation

What i want to do is this:

IF(C19 CHANGED VALUE; E24=TODAY(); DO NOTHING)

I understood that this has to be done in VBA. The examples online work diffrently from what i want to do (those work with offsets etc). How would i do this in excel?

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Are you asking how to work in VBA in Excel? What research have you done? What have you tried? What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Possible VBA solution (simple but not optimal)

In common module:

```
Public Current_C19_Formula As String
```

In Workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Current_C19_Formula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19").Formula
End Sub
```

In Worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not (Intersect(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
    If Current_C19_Formula <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19").Formula Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E24").Value = Date
        Current_C19_Formula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19").Formula
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

You must take into account that each change in C19 which cause E24 reassign will clear application's Undo buffer.

Comment: I tried to set this up but for some reason it doesnt work. I changed the sheet1 to the correct sheet names but cant get it to work. Could you please look if i did it correctly?

https://paste.pics/7E5OY

Comment: @NickJ You have not specified correct sheet name in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E24").Value = Date`. It is to be `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OnderdeelTemplate").Range("E24").Value = Date`.

Comment: I got it to work! Two more questions; 
1. This doesnt seem to work if the trigger cell is changed by a formula. (summed value that changes -> doesnt trigger the vba script to update the date). 2. Is it possible to trigger on a range ("D10:D13"). when i tried that, it gives me an out of range error.

Comment: *This doesnt seem to work if the trigger cell is changed by a formula.* Of course. Do the same in `Worksheet_Calculate()` based on created and stored `Current_C19_Value` and without `Target` check.